# ChromeDrive on Solaris (Joyent's SmartOS)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, joyent, smartos

I have a NodeJs app and I'm trying to use Selenium on SmartOS which is based on Solaris. In order to proceede I've installed selenium-webdriver (from NPM), but the package requires ChromeDriver. When I try to install the ChromeDriver I get:

Unexpected platform or architecture: sunos ia32
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0

I tried getting it from here as well: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html but I'm also running into problems.

Any ideas? All I want to do is use Selenium through my NodeJs app running on SmartOS.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in, unfortunately my app has been running on SmartOS for a while and I already have paying subscribers, I don't want to make any huge changes.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the home page https://npmjs.org/package/selenium-webdriver it says it

> In addition to the npm package, you will to download the WebDriver
>   implementations you wish to utilize. As of 2.34.0, selenium-webdriver
>   natively supports the ChromeDriver. Simply download a copy and make
>   sure it can be found on your PATH. The other drivers (e.g. Firefox,
>   Internet Explorer, and Safari), still require the standalone Selenium
>   server.

So if you can't get or compile a copy of the chromeDriver, maybe you can use a version from before 2.34.0. As it says, I suspect you will also need to download and install the Selenium Server as well

---

Alternatively the https://npmjs.org/package/selenium-node-webdriver might work better as it uses phantomjs which is a headless webdriver

> This module provides a simple wrapper around the Node.js WebDriver
>   implementation that ships with Selenium.
>
> Prerequisites
>
> Node.js
>
> PhantomJS 1.8+

EDIT

This thread here talks about installing phantomjs on smartOS/Solaris https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10521

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and haveing a look at my problem. I tried Selenium-Node-Webdriver before (I also had Selenium itself installed as well) but I was getting errors as well. Just now I settled on Zombie.Js, works great and doesn't create any problems on SmartOS.